# How can I create a sound with Java without special effects being added to it?

Tags: java, audio

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. This is the code I'm using to play sounds:

```
private void playSound(int num) {
    if (num < 0) {
        return;
    }
    MidiChannel channel = synth.getChannels()[0];
    final int note = (int) (127f / maxNum * num);
    channel.noteOn(note, 80);
}
```

All the MIDI channels have some kind of reverb or added effects on them. I tried stopping the sound after sleeping for a given amount of time (tried using both noteOff and noteOn with a velocity of 0), but the note never stops playing when I call these methods. For context, I'm trying to recreate one of those [sorting algorithm visualizers](https://youtu.be/kPRA0W1kECg), so I want the sounds being played to sound similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

The reverb is tied to MIDI CC 91. You need to set a message to that controller with value `0` , before sending `channel.noteOn` message. Maybe you want to set to `0` all other effects, so take a look at [Control change messages specifications](https://www.midi.org/specifications-old/item/table-3-control-change-messages-data-bytes-2)